# Creating a Calculated Time Periods Hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx

In order to give a nicer Cube browsing experience to end users, I am trying to create a Time Periods hierarchy consisting of Calculated Members.

---

Currently I have used a Calculated Column in my DSV to create a column with the same value on every row in my Dates table (value is `All Time`).  Then within my `Date and Time` dimension I have created a single level, single member hierarchy using that Calculated Column, which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Single level, single member hierarchy]

---

Now what I have already successfully done is add Time Periods to my `Calendar` hierarchy with the following calculation:

```mdx
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Calendar].[All].[Last 30 Days]
 AS SUM(LastPeriods(30,StrToMember(
    "[Completion Date].[Calendar].[Day]."+
    "&["+CStr(Year(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Month(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Day(Now()))+"]"
))),VISIBLE = 1;
```

This works as expected on the `Calendar` hierarchy:

[image: Screenshot of Calculation working successfully on Calendar Hierarchy]

But I want to move these into the new `Time Periods` hierarchy to keep them nicely separated.

---

So far I have tried to do this in two different ways:

1. Changing the destination Hierarchy of the Computed Member. Changing `CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Calendar].[All].[Last 30 Days]` to `CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 30 Days]`.
2. Changing the Visibility of the Calculated Member on the `Calendar` hierarchy to `VISIBLE = 0` and creating a second Caculated Member on the `Time Periods` hierarchy which references it: (I have tried with and without using the `SUM()` function)

```mdx
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 30 Days]
 AS SUM([Completion Date].[Calendar].[All].[Last 30 Days]),
VISIBLE = 1;
```

But neither of these have worked for me.  So my question is, How can I complete what I am trying to achieve?

My end goal is to have a Hierarchy which the user can drag into a pivot table and see the following (but with the Time Periods actually calculated):

[image: Screenshot of Goal]

Comment: How do you create `Time Period` hierarchy? Is it 1-member `All Time`, linked to dummy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just created the same this way:

1) Add dummy attribute for unfiltered values with the name 'All Time'
    (key is int with 0 value)

2) Add 3 empty members

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Report Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 30 Days]
 AS 
null,
VISIBLE = 1;
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Report Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 60 Days]
 AS 
null,
VISIBLE = 1;
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Report Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 90 Days]
 AS 
null,
VISIBLE = 1;
```

3) Than add scopes (I have another key format):

```
/* SCOPES */
SCOPE ([Report Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 30 Days]);
THIS = Sum(LastPeriods(30,StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].[Day].&["+CStr(Format(Now(),"yyyyMMdd"))+"]")));
END SCOPE;
SCOPE ([Report Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 60 Days]);
THIS = Sum(LastPeriods(60,StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].[Day].&["+CStr(Format(Now(),"yyyyMMdd"))+"]")));
END SCOPE;
SCOPE ([Report Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 90 Days]);
THIS = Sum(LastPeriods(90,StrToMember("[Report Date].[Report Date].[Day].&["+CStr(Format(Now(),"yyyyMMdd"))+"]")));
END SCOPE;
```

It works (also add a measure to count members of a level to validate):

[image: LastNDays]

Comment: Could you confirm where I put the Scope statements? I've added them to the end of my Calculations but when I browse the cube I see `(null)` next to Last 30 Days etc.

Comment: Yes, the very end of Calculations. Do you substitute keys for the day level?

Comment: I've managed to fix it now. The issue was my Dummy Attribute wasn't linked to my Day Attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Alex Peshik's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28501719/2594742) I have managed to get this to work.

Here is the method I have now used to setup a Calculated Time Periods Hierarchy:

1. Go into your DSV and create a `New Named Calculation` on your Date table with a name like `TimePeriod` and set the Value to be something like `All Time`.
2. Within your Date dimension create a new Attribute from that Named Calculation and use it to make a Hierarchy.
3. Make sure the New Attribute is linked to your Day Attribute in the `Attribute Relationships` tab.
4. Within your cube, go to the Calculations tab and create a Dummy Calculated Member in the `Time Period` hierarchy we have made for each time period you want to add:

```mdx
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 30 Days]
    AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1;
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 60 Days]
    AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1;
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 90 Days]
    AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1;
// etc...
```

5. Now at the bottom of your Calculation you add a Scope for each Dummy Calculation we made in the last step (you will need to change the bit within the `StrToMember()` function to match your day attribute Key):

```mdx
SCOPE ([Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 30 Days]);
    THIS = SUM(LastPeriods(30, StrToMember(
        "[Completion Date].[Calendar].[Day]."+
        "&["+CStr(Year(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Month(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Day(Now()))+"]"
    )));
END SCOPE;

SCOPE ([Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 60 Days]);
    THIS = SUM(LastPeriods(60, StrToMember(
        "[Completion Date].[Calendar].[Day]."+
        "&["+CStr(Year(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Month(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Day(Now()))+"]"
    )));
END SCOPE;

SCOPE ([Completion Date].[Time Period].[All].[Last 90 Days]);
    THIS = SUM(LastPeriods(90, StrToMember(
        "[Completion Date].[Calendar].[Day]."+
        "&["+CStr(Year(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Month(Now()))+"]&["+CStr(Day(Now()))+"]"
    )));
END SCOPE;
```