# MDX Calculated Member displays no value in Excel but same query works in SSMS

Tags: excel, mdx

I have a calculated member (not measure) of a dimension, which works in SSMS, but doesn't work in Excel 2013.

I've followed the advice described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499462/creating-a-calculated-time-periods-hierarchy/28504962#28504962) question on how to create calculated members.

So I have a new attribute in my lottery dimension called 'Relative Lotteries' with a single member 'All Lotteries in Scope' defined through the DSV.

I have a calculated member like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Lottery].[Relative Lotteries].[All].[This Lottery]
AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1;
```

Then a SCOPE Statement like this:

```
SCOPE ([Lottery].[Relative Lotteries].[All].[This Lottery]
      ,[Lottery].[Lottery Number].members);  
    THIS = 10000;--([Lottery].[Lottery Number].currentmember,measures.currentMember);  
END SCOPE;
```

I've tried loads of combinations of SCOPE and THIS = , most of which work through SSMS but none work through Excel 2013.

I used OLAP extensions to get the MDX script generated by Excel 2013, The MDX is:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Response - Sale Amt], [Measures].[Response - Qty of Orders] }      DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY Hierarchize (
 {
  DrilldownLevel (
   { [Lottery].[Relative Lotteries].[All] }
   ,
   ,
   , INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS
  )
 }
) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME
, HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM [Lottery]
WHERE ( [Lottery].[Lottery Number].&[141] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
, FORMAT_STRING
, LANGUAGE
, BACK_COLOR
, FORE_COLOR
```

Through SSMS this query yields the expected result:

[image]

But through Excel 2013, I get this result:

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that its something to do with the Excel connection string. However its difficult to test. Excel won't let me remove or add any properties, it just returns the connection string back to how it was before editing. My Excel Connection string is:

Provider=MSOLAP.6;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Cube_Name;Data Source=ServerName;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error

I've been banging my head against a brick wall trying to work this out. Any ideas ???

Comment: I don't think the conn string will be the issue. As an experiment if you amend your scope statement do numbers come through to xl? Specifically I was wondering what happens if play with this bit `SCOPE ([Lottery].[Relative Lotteries].[All].[This Lottery]
      ,[Lottery].[Lottery Number].members);  `

Comment: Have you tried removing the `,[Lottery].[Lottery Number].members` bit from your scope? So that it's just the member you're targeting